# Could the repetition of Ids cause random errors concerning viewstate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, viewstate, web-controls

The asp.net accept repetitive Ids for asp.net server controls in different template fields .

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HDN_MainCode" Value='<%#Eval("v_main_code")%>' runat="server" /> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

---

in another grid view :

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HDN_MainCode" Value='<%#Eval("v_main_code")%>' runat="server" /> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

---

Could this type of repeating cause random errors concerning viewstate ?
and if the answer is yes , How could i detect all the repetition in `.aspx` document

Comment: How do you have your ClientIdMode set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could this type of repeating cause random errors concerning viewstate
>   ?

No. These inner controls gets a **unique ID** at rendering. For example If you have lable ID `ProductIDLabel` in your `ListView`, then its generated ID would be something like:

```
ListView1$ctrl0$ProductIDLabel
ListView1$ctrl1$ProductIDLabel
```

For more see: [ASP.NET Web Server Control Identification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> When the control is inside a data-bound control that creates multiple
>   instances of the control, the value that you assign to the ID property
>   is concatenated with the naming container and with an incrementing
>   index.

**But if** you have [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) set to `Static`, then you will get the ID same as the one specified in the ASPX page.